# data structure about Graph sequential expression

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, graph

Hi I have read about the sequential expresion about graph but I can't understand the element of the array's elements.

The book says:

[image: graph G4's]

sequential expression is as below.[image]

**I want to know how to get the each array's elements.**

And this book also says,

> The node[i] is the start point of the vertex, and node[n] (n is the vertex and e is edge) is set by n+2e+1.
>
> Vertex 'i' and adjacent vertexes are saved in node[i] ... node[i+1]-1

I can't understand what this sentences mean.

Answer (score 0):

It says that all vertices are stored in `node`. And that vertex `i` is stored in `node[i]`. If you want vertex 3, you use `node[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a bit on Eduard's answer (which is correct but maybe too concise):

In this representation, the first `n` array values serve as indices into the rest of the data. Let's say you want to get connectivity of node 1: you read `nodes[1] == 11` - that is offset of node 1's adjacency, similarly `nodes[2] == 13` - offset of node 2's adjacency, so values from `nodes[11]` up to (but not including) `nodes[13]` are indices of node 1's neighbors - in this case, `[3, 0]`.

Note that `nodes[8] == 23` is an extra value pointing beyond the size of `nodes` and indicating end of offset storage. This allows to access adjacency of an arbitrary node `i` as `nodes[nodes[i]] .. nodes[nodes[i+1]-1]` - this is expressed naturally in C/C++ loops.

A similar, but arguably more often used format, is [Compressed Sparse Row](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/graph/doc/compressed_sparse_row.html), where the two parts of `nodes` (offsets and adjacency lists) are stored as two separate arrays.